# What does the divergence in 2-D physically represent if anything?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My question begs an explanation.  Allow me to use an example , let us say the vector field F equals the vector (x,y)  so that in calculating the derivative of each variable and adding we get 2.  Classically this is supposed to represent net flow out.  This is a single number that must be applied to the entire vector field.

The divergence represents the net flow out since the vector length is smaller near the origin so there is a value of 2 net flow out.  The book says to imagine a box of some area with a flow in and a flow out and obviously there is a net flow out which is represented by 2.

My question is naive but what does this represent?  You can't get something from nothing....physically if I have less going into a space I sure am not going to get more going out. Isn't  this some mathematical  representation of the magnitude of the slopes of x and y when they are summed at any point? Thank you for reading this.

Comment: So, if you were modelling the actual flow of a substance satisfying a conservation law, then this vector field would be a really bad model for it. You'd want a vector field with divergence zero ...

Comment: Let's say instead you were using it to model the magnetic field of a point charge. The divergence would be zero except at the charge itself. The divergence at the charge tells you a lot about that charge.

Comment: Yes , that clears it up.thank you and  ....I should be more patient ..and finish the rest of the chapter before jumping to conclusions.   You are saying that this particular vector field does not represent  the behavior for something that I image to have conservation laws.

Comment: They can represent sources to the vector field, imagine the 2D flow of water on a flat plane due to a faucet pouring water on the surface, or a drain under a large body of water (negative divergence). Or like the above comment there are physical objects that create the electromagnetic fields we see in day to day physics